# Rails 3 embedded widget: show.js.erb doesn't appear to work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe, widget

I've got two localhost webservers running (webrick); one at port 3000 (server) and one at 3001 (webpage). But this is pointless because it seems to be broken on the server-side.

On the "server", if I go to 'http://localhost:3000/projects/5.js', nothing loads. I get a white screen and 'view page source' is not even available as as options.

I'm guessing that document.write is the problem but I can't troubleshoot it because nothing is loading. Is there a route that I need maybe? Is there something different that I need to do in my projects/show action?

```
####The website embedded code:
<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/projects/5.js"></iframe>

####projects_controller.rb
def widget
   @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])    
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :layout => 'application_project' }
    format.json { render json: @project }
  end
end

####projects/show.js.erb
document.write("<%= escape_javascript(content_tag(:iframe, '', :src => widget_project_url(@project))).html_safe %>");

####projects/widget.html.erb
<div id="project-embed-widget">
    <h3><%= link_to @project.name, @project %></h3>
    <% if @project.funding? %>
        <h4>
        <% if @project.backers.nil? %>
            0
        <% else %>
            <%= @project.backers.count %>
        <% end %>
        BACKERS</h4>
        <% @project.calc_goal_collected %>
        <h4><%= number_to_currency(@project.goal_collected, :unit => "$") %></h4>
        <h4>PLEDGED OF <%= number_to_currency(@project.goal, :unit => "$") %> GOAL</h4>
        <h4><%= @project.time_to_go[:time] %>
        <%= @project.time_to_go[:unit].upcase %> TO GO</h4>
        <br />
        <%= render "funding_message" %>
        <br />
  <% else %>
      <%= @project.about %>
  <% end %>
  </div>

####routes.rb
resources :projects do
  member do
    get 'widget'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one thing I noticed is that you're calling `<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/projects/5.js"></iframe>` but **js** isn't one of your response formats in the controller.  Add `format.js` to the respond_to block.